# How to create sub folders in Android FileSystem

Tags: android, filesystems

I have created a file in Android file system.For this i have written the below code

```
   openFileOutput("one.html",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

using the code i have seen the file named "one.html"  is created in Android FileSystem.The Absolute is as follows.

```
   /data/data/packagename/files/one.html
```

But now i need to create a folder named "html" inside the files directory.How can i create?

Answer (score 5):

Use `getFilesDir()` to get a `File` object pointing at your application's internal storage (in your case, `/data/data/packagename/files`. From there, use standard Java I/O:

```
File subdir=new File(getFilesDir(), "whatever");

subdir.mkdirs();
```